# Resolution of type failed in child container but succeeded in parent container

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism, ioc-container

I have Prism application with two modules where one (SecondModule) depends on another (FirstModule). I'm also using log4net and I would like to have separate logger for every module. Thus I try to user child containers. The SecondModule makes it this way

```
public class Module : IModule
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

    public Module(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.container = container.CreateChildContainer();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterServices();
        RegisterViews();
    }

    private void RegisterServices()
    {
        container.RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetLogger("PATSEARCH"));
        //register all other services
        container.RegisterType<IPatientSearchService, PatientSearchService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }

    private void RegisterViews()
    {
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainMenu, () => container.Resolve<PatientSearch>());
        //register other views
    }
}
```

`PatientSearch` is a user control that is configured to auto-wire view model as its datasource and this viewmodel has contructor parameter `IPatientSearchService`. Now the problem is that when Prism tries to resolve `IPatientSearchService` during view-model auto-wiring it fails with exception

`The current type, PatientSearchModule.Services.IPatientSearchService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?`

The thing is if I replace `this.container = container.CreateChildContainer();` with `this.container = container` inside module contructor everything works fine. What is the problem with child container in this case?

**EDIT:** after some investigation I think I know the reason. The problem is that ViewModelLocator uses default container (which is parent container in my case) for resolving view-model. So new question is: how can I reconfigure it to use proper container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ViewModelLocationProvider.Register method. This lets you set up a mapping for any given view type to provide a factory method that constructs the appropriate ViewModel (such as using your child container).